# What's wrong with this enum lookup map?

Tags: java

I have an enum where the reverse-lookup table I created for it returns null for all values. I added an assert after the lookup table is created, and sure enough, it's empty. I feel like this is something simple and obvious that I'm overlooking because I use this exact same structure for all my enums and they work fine.

```
public enum TerrainType {
ROAD(1),
PLAINS(2),
FOREST(3),
MOUNTAINS(4);

private static final Map<Byte,TerrainType> lookup = new HashMap<Byte,TerrainType>();

private final byte terrainId;

static {
    for(TerrainType type : EnumSet.allOf(TerrainType.class)) {
        lookup.put(type.getByte(),type);
    }
    assert lookup.get(1) != null; // <--- THIS ASSERT FIRES, WHY?
} 

TerrainType(int id) {
    assert id > 0 && id < 128: "ID must be from 1 to 127"; 
    this.terrainId = (byte) id;
}

public static TerrainType get(int id) {
    return lookup.get(id);
}

public byte getByte() {
    return this.terrainId;
}
}
```

Comment: Your Map uses Byte while your map (in assertion expression) tries to use Integer

Comment: Because lookup.get(1) returns ROAD, which is not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal 1 is an integer.

This works.

```
assert lookup.get(Integer.valueOf(1).byteValue()) != null
```

Alternatively, you could change your `terrainId` to be of type `int`

Comment: That's it. Most of my other enums are integers.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.  Note the changes.

I'd recommend not using assert to enforce your contract.  Throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if you get unexpected input.

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum TerrainType
{
    ROAD(1),
    PLAINS(2),
    FOREST(3),
    MOUNTAINS(4);

    private static final Map<Integer, TerrainType> lookup = new HashMap<Integer, TerrainType>();

    private final int terrainId;

    static
    {
        for (TerrainType type : EnumSet.allOf(TerrainType.class))
        {
            lookup.put(type.getTerrainId(), type);
        }
        assert lookup.get(1) != null; // <--- THIS ASSERT FIRES, WHY?
    }

    TerrainType(int id)
    {
        assert id > 0 && id < 128 : "ID must be from 1 to 127";
        this.terrainId = id;
    }

    public static TerrainType lookupById(int id)
    {
        return lookup.get(id);
    }

    public int getTerrainId()
    {
        return this.terrainId;
    }
}

class TerrainTypeDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            System.out.println(TerrainType.lookupById(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's equals(Object) problem.

**Quoting Java API:**

"if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)), then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null"

Try this piece of code:

```
int a = 1;
byte b = (byte) a;
Byte c = b;
boolean d = c.equals(1);
System.out.println(d);
```